# Where's the Tipsy plugin for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tooltip

I'm unable to find the download link for the Tipsy plugin
http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

The jQuery project page for the plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tipsy) does not have a download link. Am I not looking in the right place?

Comment: You could check it out from github - the bottom of the project page provides the command:git clone git://github.com/jaz303/tipsy.git    Edit: the project page also has downloads http://github.com/jaz303/tipsy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[As found in the source code](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js)

Comment: Make sure to also use the newer [CSS file](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/stylesheets/tipsy.css) and [arrow image](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/images/tipsy.gif).